# How to change grub2 in CentOS/RHEL7 from UUID to old style device?

Tags: centos7, rhel7, grub2, uuid

With CentOS/RHEL 7 there are a couple of changes (compared to CO/RHEL 6).
One of it is the use of **grub2** instead of *grub*.

Per default the OS seems to use a UUID to "find" the boot-device.

Is there an easy to use receipe to get back to device-names (like /dev/sda1) instead?

Background of the question:
I am intending to clone additional VMs from a template. Base is a new (virtual) disk device with a different UUID.

If I can not revert to **sda1** I will need to change the UUID of the clone in the **grub.cfg** to the new UUID - which is plan "B".

**Update** 2017-10-26

The kernel-parameter for **root=** will be changed to the disk - see the answer from [*Thomas*](https://serverfault.com/a/876651/77281) below.

There remains a problem with this section, generated by **grub2-mkconfig**:

> ```
>     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  716433ab-9e30-42a7-a272-6c66243499d2
>     else
>       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 716433ab-9e30-42a7-a272-6c66243499d2
>     fi
> ```

This still contains the search for the UUID. If it can't be found, the boot-process will go to error "not found" or something like that. After pressing ENTER the system will boot up ok.

The remaining Q is how to inactivate that section (I did not find the place to disable the **feature_platform_search_hint**)?

Comment: I don't understand, there is no regression with GRUB2, my line is as follows: `linux /vmlinuz-4.11.0-1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/vg--main-root ro single acpi_enforce_resources=lax` Work perfectly with VMs.

Comment: @moutonjr I suspect this is specific for RHEL7 and/or the way it builds/parses the grub2 entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible by adding the parameter as follows to `/etc/default/grub`.

```
$ echo "GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true" >> /etc/default/grub
$ grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

If you want to double check the result before.

```
$ grub2-mkconfig | less
```

---

#### Update

To completely disable the UUID in *GRUB*, you need to add the line as follows to */etc/sysconfig/grub*

```
$ echo "GRUB_DISABLE_UUID=true" >> /etc/default/grub
$ grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Looks good. I will give it a try. Can you Link your answer to a source for that Info?

Comment: Sorry, don't get your question? I just looked at the scripts in `/etc/grub.d` to find the config option.

Comment: I tried, but the config still searches for UUIDs, but it also appended other search options. I need to clone the VM to test it...

Comment: Could you precise a bit what you have done and which config...double check that `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` is in the `/etc/default/grub` and check what `grub2-mkconfig | grep root=` returns.

Comment: I updated my Q with further details - if you can solve this too, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Yep - the GRUB_DISABLE_UUID did the job.